# What is ssl certification error and what does the following code do?

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a course in coursera and this code is part of web scraping program...I dont know what it does

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

Comment: You should ask Coursera for your money back since they're [disabling hostname checking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.check_hostname) without telling you why

Comment: First of all coursera is free for our college....Second I am new to this web scrapping and the teacher in the video said to look what the code does in stack overflow:)